# Is placing a boolean-returning method inside an if functionally equivalent to calling the method directly?

Tags: java, methods, if-statement

I'm updating some code, and I have a void method (validateFile) that tests files and writes failures directly to some log files. I want to add a counter for each file that passes, but I don't want to lose the logging that's done in case of failure.

In terms strictly of the validateFile method running successfully, is this:

```
validateFile(filename);
```

functionally equivalent to this? (assuming I change the return type to boolean and put return statements in correctly)

```
if(validateFile(filename)){
   passCount++;
}
```

If it is equivalent, is there a reason (best practices, etc.) that I shouldn't do this?

Comment: What do you mean by functionally equivalent?  In the second case, something extra happens.  But in both cases, the function gets executed.

Comment: Functionally equivalent strictly in terms of validateFile executing in its entirety. I couldn't think of a reason why it wouldn't, but I didn't want to create a situation a year from now where my coworkers have to come back to this and are cursing me for setting it up this way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is equivalent. No, there is no reason I can think of that you should not do this.

Just one possible caveat that comes to mind, take care when mixing this with conditional operators:

```
if (a() && b());
```

In that case, `b()` will be called if and only if `a()` returns `true`.

Comment: Good catch. +1 for taking care of that problem.

Comment: I won't in this case, but should I need to do that in the future, would if(a() & b()); work to avoid the short circuit?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is equivalent; there is no reason why this might be inferior to the original code.

You could also do the same thing on a single line, like this:

```
passCount += validateFile(filename) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks for the example of the ternary operator; I'm relatively new to dev work, and that was a new one for me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code will work this way, it will compile. And it is actually the best way to go about it, most of the time.

EDIT: Assuming, that in the first case, you are binding it to a variable and placing that one in an if. Else, not so much, the first one wont work.

Answer (score 1):

The latter one has better separation of concerns. I would prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `if(validateFile(filename))` will run `validateFile(filename)` in exactly the normal way. Once it returns — assuming it returns normally (as opposed to throwing an exception) — its return value will be used exactly as you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work.

Calling methods this way is pretty standard.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is equivalent. It is just like:

```
boolean result = validateFile(filename);
if(result){
   passCount++;
}
```